# Synonymous word in hindi or kannada language

Tags: vedanta, advaita, adi-shankaracharya

In vedanta an *upadhi* is a **limiting adjunct**. Here is my doubt. What is the translation word for **limiting adjunct** in hindi or kannada language. Because I nowhere find the translation word for ***limiting adjunct***. Could anyone answer for the same. And what exactly mean by the words ***limiting*** and ***adjunct***.

Comment: Questions about translations are mostly off-topic on Hinduism.SE.

Answer (score 1):

First, in what context and in which Vedantic text (Upanishad) does it say Upadhi is a limited supplement? Please share that.

Second, the word for Adjunct in Sanskrit = परिशिष्टम्.
The term परिशिष्टम् is mainly used in Vedic documents when an alternative Shaka or version of the same text (a chapter) is appended as an additional supplement to the first one. Such supplements are proprietary or limited to specific Vedic shakas (schools). I am pasting an image here to show this.

परिमित = means to have a limited scope/reach.
सावधि = means limitation.
Both are adjectives

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Shankaracharya's Atmabodha, cited from

https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/what-is-upadhi-limiting-adjunct

In Atmabodh Bhagavan Adi Shankaracharya says

> नानोपाधि- वशादेव जातिनामाश्- रमादयः । आत्मन्यारो- पितास्तोये- रसवर्णादिभ- ेदवत् ॥११॥
> nanopadhivashadeva- jaatinaamashramaadayaH |aatmanyaaropitastoye rasavarnaadibhedavat

> (Because of its association with different conditionings (upadhis), the idea of caste, color, position and so on, are superimposed upon the Atman, just as flavor, color, and so on, are superimposed on water.)

Speakingtree says:

> In Sanskrit Upadhi is defined as - उपसमिपे स्थित्वा स्वीयान् गुणान् अन्यत्र आदधाति (upasamipe sthitva sveeyaan guNan anyatra aadadhaati) staying near something it transfers its property to something else e.g. a crystal kept on a blue cloth appears blue.

The last sentence - translated to Hindi, reads

> किसी चीज के पास रहकर वह अपनी गुण को किसी और चीज में स्थानांतरित कर देता है उदा। नीले कपड़े पर रखा क्रिस्टल नीला दिखाई देता है।